# Octobercms Component Twig

Tags: javascript, html, twig, uniqueidentifier, octobercms

Can someone show me how to set unique Id for components?
I only know I have to put this code in my default.htm

```
{% set uid = '{{__SELF__.id}}' %}
```

how to use it in javascript?

and what is this for?

```
var avatar_{{uid}} = {{ avatar }};
```

for example this is my js

```
$(function(){
    $("#tab-close").click(function() {        
         $("#tab").addClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

How do I set a unique Id for it so that when I duplicate the component both can still work normally without errors?

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to encapsulate your control with a single identifier, like this

```
<div id="mycontrol{{ __SELF__.id }}">
   ...
</div>
```

Then in JavaScript, you can target elements inside:

```
function initTabs(controlEl) {
    var $control = $(controlEl)
    $(".tab-close", $control).click(function() {        
         $(".tab", $control).addClass("hidden");
    });
}
```

The code above targets the class names found only inside the `$control` container. You would call this function from the markup like so

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        initTabs('#mycontrol{{ __SELF__.id }}');
    });
</script>
```